# How to write a rule for pdf file that exist in a folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I write a rule for files that already exist in a folder to point to a different location. In example, for rewrite any request to a pdf file in the `wp-content/uploads/` folder to a page `download/?q=$1`.

I have seen in SO a [related question for moved pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776591/714967) with the following

```
# checks that the request is for a file that *does not* exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
# make sure we've not already redirected to the uploads directory 
# (in case it doesn't exist in there either)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/uploads/
# the rule matches against either pdf, zip or xls.
RewriteRule ([^/]*\.(pdf|zip|xls))$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

But I want the opposite effect. Make the redirection for my existing files and keep a 404 not found for non-existing files.

I have tried different approach without no luck. Wondering if the default `.htaccess` file of WordPress within the root folder if interfering with this one. How to rewrite all requests of a pdf to a custom page?

EDIT:

The `.htaccess` file is located in the `wp-content/uploads`folder.

Regarding the WordPress Rewrite API I already have the following function in a custom plugin:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $new_rules = array(
    'exams/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=exams&type=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]',
    'exams/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/subject/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=exams&type=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]&subject=$matches[3]'
        );

    return $aRules + $new_rules;
}
```

From my understanding, these functions allows us to specify additional rewrite rules for WordPress as described in the [Rewrite API/add rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) documentation. So, It should not affect the content of the rules specified in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Kindly your question is not very clear. Please try this one in your main `.htaccess` file: `RewriteRule ^.*\.pdf$ /wp-content/download/ [R=301,L]`. It works on files with .pdf extension. Or this one too `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(pdf)` + `RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /wp-content/download/ [R,L]` Both with `RewriteEngine On` before

Comment: @LoicTheAztec. You are totally right. I tried to ask the question while exposing the problem somewhat frustrated and I have forgotten what was the goal. I rewritten the question.

Comment: Your WP installation might have some plugins installed and that may skip .htaccess rules and serve files from cache.

Comment: Reading again your question I've noticed you wonder _if the default .htaccess file of WordPress within the root folder if interfering with this one_.  Where exactly is **this one** located?

Comment: @anubhava I'm using a _Redirection_ plugin *but* I have disabled it for making all these tests. Anyway, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @JordiNebot The .htaccess file is located in the wp-content/uploadsfolder. I have updated the question with new details.

Comment: Verify if `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` is enabled  by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your WP is installed on the root of your domain, it'd be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/
RewriteRule ([^\/]+\.pdf)$ /download.php?q=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

The first line (removing the `!` from your example code) matches only existing files, so if the PDF file doesn't exist you'll get the standard 404.

The second condition restricts the matches to only existing files on the `/wp-content/uploads/` folder, so http://example.com/example.pdf won't be redirected.

Finally, the `RewriteRule` (affected by the two precedent conditions) redirects any existing file on your uploads folder ending with a `.pdf` extension to `/downloads.php` passing the filename as `q` parameter.

So, `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/filename.pdf` will be redirected to `http://example.com/download.php?q=filename.pdf` if `filename.pdf` exists in the `/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/` folder.

I've checked this solution in a local dummy WP install and it works, so I hope this helps.

---

**Edit:** If you have an `.htaccess` in your *uploads* folder, only with this should be enough:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ([^\/]+\.pdf)$ /download.php?q=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Have you tried what's been suggested on comments (putting some garbage in your `.htaccess` to check if it's enabled)?

Another shoot would be to move the rules to the root `.htaccess`...

Comment: I understand the rules you have proposed but they do not work. However, if I change the first one to `!-f` then I'm redirected to `/download.php/q=file.pdf` if _file.pdf_ does not exist but does is not the behaviour expected. So, I'm wondering if it could be related to some other behaviour on the hosting side?

Comment: Well, Wordpress has it's own [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API), but I'd go with some tests first... Try removing both `RewriteCond` lines to check if any *.pdf URL gets redirected. Also, my answer assumes your URL contains no query string data...

Comment: Your second suggestion worked. I'm have the _Redirection_ plugin installed and my own rewrite rules by adding the filter _rewrite_rules_array_. I'm wondering if it could be related with some cache issue. I would appreciate if you explain the NC, L and R meaning and consequences of omit.

Comment: Yes, of course. _NC_ stands for _no-case_, meaning that the rule matching is made case insensitve. _L_ is for _last_, so if this rule matches no further rules are considered after it. _R=301_ does the redirection with a 301 (Moved permanently) header. You can find more information about redirection codes and _mod_rewrite_ flags in [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following as first rule in your /wp-content/uploads/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.pdf)$ /download/?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect **/wp-content/uploads/foo.pdf** to **/download/?q=foo.pdf** .

If you want to externally redirect **/wp-content/uploads/foo.pdf** to **/download/?q=foo.pdf** (changing the url bar from old location to new location)  use the full url in Rewrite target eg **http://example.com/download/?q=foo.pdf** or add the **R** Redirect  flag **[NC,L,R]**

Comment: It does not work (neither of the two options). I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding something with this topic. When I access to `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/foo.pdf` I see the pdf file and no redirection is done. The `.htaccess`file is placed in the `wp-content/uploads` but it neither work if I place the rule in the default `.htaccess` shipped with WordPress in the root of the site.

Comment: @PQb I have updated the rule, you can now use it in **/wp-contents/upload/.htaccess** .